# I'm looking for a solution, to remove the item on the right position in the Adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got stuck today with coding because I was trying to remove a child on the Firebase Realtime Database and at the same time to remove the item from the **ArrayList** and the wrong view has been removed from the **RecyclerView**.

Also, the same thing works well on another fragment and I have no idea why.

Here is my method for populating the **Recyclerview** in the Fragment:

```java
private void populateRV(ArrayList<Task> myTasksArrayList) {

    MyTasksAdapter myTasksAdapter = new MyTasksAdapter(myTasksArrayList, getActivity());
    myTasksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    myTasksRV.setAdapter(myTasksAdapter);
    myTasksRV.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    myTasksRV.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    // query.removeEventListener(this);
}
```

This method above is called in a `ValueEventListener`, to get the data and to add it to the `ArrayList`.

And here is the `onBindViewHolder`:

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyTasksViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    title = myTasksArrayList.get(position).getTitle();
    category = myTasksArrayList.get(position).getCategory();
    description = myTasksArrayList.get(position).getDescription();
    helperName = myTasksArrayList.get(position).getHelperName();
    timeStamp = myTasksArrayList.get(position).getTimestamp();

    holder.taskTitle.setText(title);
    holder.taskCategory.setText(category);
    holder.taskDescription.setText(description);
    holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            myTasksArrayList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());

            removeChildFromDatabase();


        }
    });
```

### PROBLEM 1:

When I press the `deleteBtn` the wrong item will be removed from the `RecyclerView`.

### PROBLEM 2:

If I remove the `ValueEnventListener`: `// query.removeEventListener(this);` will remove the right item BUT after if I add an item to the list will not show, because the `ValueEnventListener` will remain removed.

Comment: I did not understand your intent specifically. Do you mean to delete an item from Firebase and modify the adapter? @Molnar Attila

Comment: What happened if you change this line `myTasksArrayList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());` become this line `myTasksArrayList.remove(position);`

Comment: Yes, delete from the Firebase and modify the adapter @AdelB-Lahlouh :)

Comment: I tried it @Ticherhaz, but it is the same thing unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a **Class of object** that sends values from Firebase Real-time and stores these values in the ArrayList of the Class of object type.

In my opinion, it is not necessary to delete every element of **RecyclerView**. modified in Firebase **at the same time** it is modified in the adapter.

> **PROBLEM 1:**

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyTasksViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        title = myTasksArrayList.get(position).getTitle();
        category = myTasksArrayList.get(position).getCategory();
        description = myTasksArrayList.get(position).getDescription();
        helperName = myTasksArrayList.get(position).getHelperName();
        timeStamp = myTasksArrayList.get(position).getTimestamp();
        holder.taskTitle.setText(title);
        holder.taskCategory.setText(category);
        holder.taskDescription.setText(description);

        holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               DatabaseReference db_node = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("//YUOR ROOT IN DATABASE");
                db_node.removeValue();
                notifyDataSetChanged(); //It reloads the adapter again
            }
        });
```

> **PROBLEM 2:**

In this problem you have to recover the data and when the application stops to avoid any other problem you should delete **removeEventListener**.

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        valueEventLis = Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                list = new ArrayList<>();

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())

             //... etc  list.add(snapshot.getValue(etc.class));                        
              populateRV(list);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

> **And:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (valueEventLis != null)
            Ref.removeEventListener(valueEventLis);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you Adel B-Lahlouh :) I will try it. I think you're right. I shouldn't delete elements from the Recyclerview one by one. I think this is where I did the mistake. I'll reply back to you soon, how it goes. :)

Comment: Ok bro, I am at your service @Molnar Attila

Comment: I tried to implement this solution and it's not working. My steps are: I add a child to the Realtime Database and after 10 sec I press the Delete button on the item on the RecyclerView and removes the last item on the list, not the one that I pressed. It's very strange...it should be something with the Firebase instance method :-?

Comment: Does delete the wrong item in Firebase?  If so make sure the reference is correct, you must give the object you want to delete the reference through list.get (position)

Comment: No, it deletes the right child. The reference is correct. There is something between the adapter and the ValueEventListener. Logically, when I remove a child, from the database, what I created, it should remove from the RecyclerView the same item, and instead of this, it removes the last one.

Comment: Although, I have the exact same method/methods in my post in another Fragment and there it works perfectly.